# How to assign the query responses to the global.arrays, not the value inside the array of global.arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, reference

**QUESTION:**

I am trying to assign to global arrays the results of queries to my MongoDB database efficiently. I essentially tried to store the references to the global arrays inside an array so that I could assign to all of them the results of the queries inside a for loop.

This does not seem to be possible. What would you suggest ?

---

**CODE:**

```
    var arrays = [global.array1, global.array2, global.array3];

    var colsArray = ["array1","array2","array3"];

    var promises = colsArray.map(col => global.fetchCollection(col));

    Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {

        for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
            arrays[d] = responses[d];
        } 

        console.log("VALUE INSIDE ARRAY of global.arrays: "+arrays[0]);
        console.log("VALUE OF global.array is still : "+global.array1);

    })
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
VALUE INSIDE ARRAY of global.arrays:: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
VALUE OF global.array is still : undefined
```

---

**N.B.:**

This would work of course. But quite unsatisfactory of course:

```
        var arrays = [global.array1, global.array2, global.array3];

        var colsArray = ["array1","array2","array3"];

        var promises = colsArray.map(col => global.fetchCollection(col));

        Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {

                global.array1 = responses[0];
                global.array2 = responses[2];
                global.array3 = responses[3];

        })
```

---

**EDIT:**

This does not work:

```
    var arrays = [global.array1, global.array2, global.array3];

    var colsArray = ["array1","array2","array3"];

    var promises = colsArray.map(col => global.fetchCollection(col));

    Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {

        for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
            arrays[colsArray[d]] = responses[d];
        } 

        console.log("VALUE INSIDE ARRAY of global.arrays: "+arrays[0]);
        console.log("VALUE OF global.array is still : "+global.array1);

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var arrays = [global.array1, global.array2, global.array3];
```

you **copy** the value in `global.array1` etc. into `arrays`. That value is called an object reference. It tells the JavaScript engine where the array is, elsewhere in memory. There is no ongoing link between `arrays[0]` and `global.array1` (for instance); they both just happen to contain the same value.

Your code **replaces** the values in `arrays`. This has no effect at all on `global.array1` etc.

If you really have an object called `global`, then you can index into it with brackets notation (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)) to actually change the value of `global.array1` like this:

```
for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
    global["array" + (d + 1)] = responses[d];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var global = {
    fetchCollection(col) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("Response for " + col);
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
        });
    }
};

var colsArray = ["array1", "array2", "array3"];

var promises = colsArray.map(col => global.fetchCollection(col));

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
    for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
        global["array" + (d + 1)] = responses[d];
    } 

    console.log("VALUE OF global.array1 is : " + global.array1);

});
```

Or if the names are not numeric like that, then you'd use your `colsArray` to get the name:

```
for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
    global[colsArray[d]] = responses[d];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var global = {
    fetchCollection(col) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("Response for " + col);
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
        });
    }
};

var colsArray = ["array1", "array2", "array3"];

var promises = colsArray.map(col => global.fetchCollection(col));

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
    for (var d = 0; d < responses.length; d++) {
        global[colsArray[d]] = responses[d];
    } 

    console.log("VALUE OF global.array1 is : " + global.array1);

});
```

But I'd strongly encourage you not to use globals at all.